# xfce clock issue

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, clock

I'm having some trouble with my new Xubuntu 14.04 installation's clock.  It seems to be lagging behind by an hour.  the `date` and `hwclock` commands are reporting the correct time.  I even tried to change my timezone to a different one and the clock didn't change at all.  Any help on fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the clock's settings? (Right-clicking it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found an odd fix to the issue.  I had to first remove the clock from the panel, then change the time to what I want, then re-add the clock to the panel.

Comment: I can't believe this worked, but it did. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. So absurd. Lost hours on this annoyance trying to fix it.

Comment: I had this same issue on Manjaro Linux 18.1.0, with xfce4-panel v. 4.14.1-0.1, and this solution worked for me. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thought it worked until I entered the timezone again. This messes up everything again. Tried disabling sync with Internet but even on manual the clock shows incorrect time. Using `date` in the terminal gets me the correct result, so it's not a system wide issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the clock in the panel
2. Select `Properties`
3. Update the timezone (it seems to use its own timezone)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the clock in the panel
2. Select Properties
3. In the "Clock Options" change the format from custom format (which defaults
   to an empty string causing this problem) to any of the options in the
   selector